# Activities slowing application

Tags: android

In my application I have a lot of activities that jump from one and other by buttons. I want to make sure that when the user clicks on a button to leave that activity, the activity is not running in the background slowing down the application. So I figured the way to solve this is to add `onStop` at the bottom of the activity like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homeactivity);

    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, activity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });

    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, activity1.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });


}
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

I need to know if this `onStop` is really stopping the activity from running in the background and slowing down the application. If not, can somebody assist me with stopping the activity from running in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling `startActivity(i);`, call `finish();`, that would ensure that your previous activity is killed and won't take up any more resources.

Also, when you override `onStop()`, you are not doing anything in it since you're just calling the `super` method of that function. In general, activity lifecycle methods are overridden if you want to ensure data continuity. For example, you have an app that takes in user input and you want to preserve it, you override the `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods to handle these kinds of situations. You do something like take in the input and store it in `SharedPreferences` in the `onPause()` method, and when the `onResume()` method is called, you take those values from the `SharedPreferences` and continue using them.

One great example is the `onCreate()` override. It is the first function that is called when an activity is initiated. In your `onCreate()`, you have your usual call for its `super` method, however, you have a lot more going on there. You can actually just have an `onCreate()` with only the call to the `super` function but that won't do you any good. In the `onCreate()` function, you set the layout and assign Button values as well as onClickListeners and other widgets that you have on your layout.

Just keep in mind that when you override an activity lifecycle method, do something in it.

Now, if you want to go back to your previous activity (the one that opened the new one) do this in your second activity:

```
@Override 
protected void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();        

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityOne.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

That will take you to your first activity and kill the second one.

Comment: `finish`(); does free up some resources but when I press the back button to go back to that activity, it takes me out of the whole application. So Do I put `onResume` at the bottom of the activity?

Comment: See my updated answer. You have to override the back button and create an intent to open the original activity.

Comment: I have put `onBackPressed` where `onStop` used to be. and everything works fine, its just that when I press the back button a black screens appears for about a half a second and then it loads the previous activity

Answer (score 2):

if you want to stop and kill current activity just call finish(); after you place intent

```
//start new activity
Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, activity1.class);
startActivity(i);
//kill current activity
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't need an activity, just after the activity starts call activity method finish(). It will kill the current one after launching an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please familiar yourself with Android [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html). The basic premise of Activity is so to structure an app's code in such a way such that Android OS can efficient manage it. For example if the new Activity you started is the game screen that requires lots of memory, Android would destroy all of your app's prior Activities, and reconstruct them when the user exiting the game Activity.

As long as your activities don't do background threading or send frequent messages to handlers, they will *not* slow down the device in any way. And as mentioned above, since all the Activities not currently in the foreground may be removed by the OS at any time, you shouldn't be doing anything with them in the first place.